# How can I save a process resource from proc_open in order to check the status later on?

Tags: java, php, drupal, shell, ubuntu-server

I'm running a sh **script** that runs a **java** process through **php** on **ubuntu** server. I'm using proc_open for running the process. usually the Workflow goes like :

- request a page ->
- script runs (until it's finished) ->
- result page.

In my case the script runs in parallel so the server won't wait until the script is  finished (it takes hours sometimes so it can't) , so I need to save that resource somehow to follow it later (status of the process or just stopping it).

The resource type is "process", I used this function [get_resource_type](http://php.net/get_resource_type) for getting it.

Serialize won't work at this case - resource is an exceptional for it (you can look at http://il2.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php inside the Parameters box).

My target is a good process handling. does someone know how can i use the resource or other way you would do for process handling.

Comment: What do you mean by 'good process handling'?

Comment: To know the real status of a process and not by indicating with files help like the first suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't store resource types for later use in PHP. What you need to do is implement some form of asynchronous communication - maybe a file, where one writes status information and the other one reads, a shared memory, a named pipe, ...

I would look into the [pcntl extension](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.pcntl.php). Hint: Forking is not possible from within a web-server environment for security reasons.

Comment: tnx ver much - I wrote the process id inside a file and handled it with unix command from php.

Answer (score 0):

> In my case the script runs in parallel so the server won't wait until the script is finished (it takes hours sometimes so it can't) ..

That shouldn't be a problem on its own. You can easily have a long running php-process, as long as it's not initiated from a web server. If you need to initiate the process from a web application, I would suggest that you insert an entry in a database table, and then have a cronjob run a script, which checks this queue and do the processing.